# The border for a picture on CSS is not running?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS stylesheets and I am trying to practice on making borders around pictures. 
Here is my HTML and CSS code if this helps:

```css
    h1{
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        color:#576D94, serif;
        
    }
    
    p{
        font-family: Garamond, serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color:#4A4943;
      
    }
    
    img{
        height:100px;
        width:300px;
        border:1px solid #4682b4;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Result</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
     </head>
     <body>
     <h1>Welcome to my webisite!</h1>
     <p>This is Alex's website welcome!!</p>
     <img src="http://entnet5.com/~c86950x1/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/small-animals.jpg" />
     </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the code I want you to look at specifically:

```
 img{
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #4682b4;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: What's wrong everything seems fine ? See https://jsfiddle.net/cpe0ugkf/

Comment: For some reason it is not running on code academy it gave me this error "Oops, try again. Did you remember to give your image a 1px solid #4682b4 border?". I'm finding it hard to understand.

Comment: I recommend you edit your question with what your problem is exactly

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that **cannot be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Also, which lesson on code academy is this issue occuring?